# Creating a connection between android application and MS SQL Server

Tags: android, mysql, sql, web-services

My code:

```
Button loginbtn;
    TextView errorlbl;
    EditText edname, edpassword;
    Connection connect;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    Statement st;
    String ipaddress, db, username, password;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private Connection ConnectionHelper(String user,String password,String database, String server)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ";database name =" + database + ";user =" + user + ";password =" + password + ";" ;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        }
        catch (SQLException se)
        {
            Log.e("Error", se.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        errorlbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_error);
        edname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        edpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

        ipaddress = "xxxxxxxxx";
        username = "xxxxxxx";
        password = "xxxxxxx";
        db = "DKMobile";

        connect = ConnectionHelper(username,password,db,ipaddress);
        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try{
                    connect = ConnectionHelper(username, password, db, ipaddress);
                    st = connect.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from DKMUsers where user_ID = '"+ edname.getText().toString()+"'and Password = '"+edpassword.getText().toString()+"'");
                    if(rs!=null && rs.next()){
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else {
                        errorlbl.setText("Sorry, wrong credentials!!!");

                    }

                }catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    errorlbl.setText(e.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

logcat:

```
>08-12 16:46:20.183    2027-2027/com.dk.dkmobile E/Error﹕ Single-Sign-On is only supported on Windows. Please specify a user name.
08-12 16:51:49.661    2027-2027/com.dk.dkmobile E/Error﹕ Single-Sign-On is only supported on Windows. Please specify a user name.
08-12 16:51:49.661    2027-2027/com.dk.dkmobile D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
08-12 16:51:49.669    2027-2027/com.dk.dkmobile E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dk.dkmobile, PID: 2027
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.Statement java.sql.Connection.createStatement()' on a null object reference
            at com.dk.dkmobile.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:83)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-12 16:51:54.120    2027-2027/com.dk.dkmobile I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2027 SIG: 9
```

As I put the values of username and password the emulator shows the message:

> Unfortunately your app has stopped working. Can anyone pointing me to resolve it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right approach to connect mobile applications with the database.
Instead you should create a middleware(REST/SOAP webservice) which runs on server.
This middleware will in turn connect with the database and your mobile app whether it is android, iOS or windows app can communicate with this middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to mysql. You should create a php/jsp or any language which runs query online and brings data in json or xml format then use asynctask for parsing those data using httpclient. It will be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

FYI, without any server communication ([Web services](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_intro.asp)) you can't use the website database in android application.

If you want to manage the communication between the website and the android app means you need a centralized server which having the data of your web/mobile applications. So, after that by using the web service methods ([REST](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html)/[SOAP](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_intro.asp)) you can achieve the communication between them